# Sunspot Solr Rails searching/sorting via JQuery Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm currently using the [sunspot_rails gem](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot) for a simple 'craigslist' ecommerce app and I want to load search results/sorting via JQuery Ajax (rather than a page request). However, I'm having difficulty getting this to work, any ideas? JQuery is working for other plugins. Thank you very much!

Search Action and sorting functions in Item Controller

```
  def search
  @search = Item.search do
     fulltext (params[:search])
     order_by sort_column, sort_direction
     end
    @items = @search.results
  end

  def sort_column
  Item.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "created_at"
 end

  def sort_direction
   %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "desc"
   end
```

search.js

```
$("#itemsfeed").html(<%= escape_javascript(render('feed')) %>);
```

Item Helper

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
  title ||= column.titleize
  css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
  direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction, :page => nil),   {:class => css_class}
  end
```

search.html.erb

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#itemsfeed th a").live("click", function() {
  $.getScript(this.href);
return false;
   });
 });
 </script>

 <% form_tag search_items_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <div class='searchbox'>
 <%= text_area_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'tags', :cols => '40', :rows => '1' %>
      </div>
   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :class => 'submitbtn' %>
   <br/>
   <div id='itemsfeed'><%= render 'feed' %></div>
 <% end %>
```

feed.html.erb

```
 <tr>
 <th><%= sortable "price" %></th>
 <th><%= sortable "created_at" %></th>
 </tr>


<%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>

<ol><%= render :partial => 'shared/item', :collection => @items  %></ol>
```

Comment: post relevant section of routes.rb. search.html.erb is specifying verb/method "get". perhaps your route only response to "post"? what does your log tell you? is it even receiving the request?

Comment: do i need to do :remote => true? and sorting works it's just not ajaxy, also routes for search: resources :items do
   collection do
    get :search
   end
  end

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have `:remote => true` in your `@form_tag` if you want the submit to be done via ajax.